# Can't see system drive Sda1

Tags: filesystem, root

I can't see my "C" drive any more (excuse the DOS notation) It doesn't show up in my home folder.The drive is partitioned into a 30GB Root and the rest reserved for data None of it shows up in my home folder.  I think it was there originally but somehow has disappeared.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Can you see the drive under the "disk utility"? You can find the utility by searching for disks in the dash or running the command gnome-disks. If you can't see the drive there, it's quite likely that the drive or cable to the drive has gone bad.

Comment: The drive is there alright it is the one i am using right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the drive under Disk Utility, you should be able to find the Windows partition and click the button that looks like a play button. From there, you should be able to mount the drive or get a specific error message we can work with.